# input text animation not working on focus out if there is no text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my search bar

When the user clicks on it, it expands with a simple animation in order to allow the user to write, and it should play the animation backwards if the user clicks on another part of the page.
The problem is that, if there is no text, the animation doesn't play backwards, it simply goes back to default size, as you can see in the gif below.
[image]

CSS

```
.searchbar {
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50%;
    outline: none;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    background-image: url('search.png');
    background-position: right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.searchbar:focus {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #E0FFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<input type="text" class="searchbar"></div>
```

Comment: It does gradually shrink down, but it's got no background color so you can't see it happening.

Comment: *"The problem is that, if there is no text, the animation doesn't play backwards, it simply goes back to default size..."* So you want a smooth transition going back. What about that text crammed in the input when it's shrunk, did you want that fixed or it's ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your codes work Properly .  and you can see at below ( i add `border` to see that ).
but your problem is because the `transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out` is set for`width` property only , set `transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out` for better view.

```css
.searchbar {
  border : 1px solid;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50%;
    outline: none;
    outline:0;
    background-image: url('search.png');
    background-position: right; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
}

.searchbar:focus {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-indent: 10px;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="searchbar"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, changing `width` with `all` solved!

Answer (score 1):

You can see in here

I apply .searchbar `background-color: transparent;`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}



body{
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin:0;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.container{
  width:50vw;
  height: 12.5vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 4rem;
}

.searchbar {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  display: block;
  border-top-right-radius: 4rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4rem;
  width: 10%;
  height: 4rem;
  outline: none; 
  border:0; 
  outline:0; 
  background-image: url('https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fassets.stickpng.com%2Fthumbs%2F585e4ad1cb11b227491c3391.png&f=1&nofb=1'); 
  background-position: right; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: contain; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size:2rem;
}

.searchbar:focus {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #E0FFFF;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  text-indent: 10px;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <input type="text" class="searchbar" id="searchbar" />
</div>
```